# Cannot get range with duration times more than 10 minutes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello I'm trying to retrieve only the durations where the time is more than 10 minutes. I'm not getting any errors but there is no result found. Seems like the comparison operator is wrong.

I'm trying to retrieve only the cells where the duration is more or equal than 10 minutes.

Here is my data.

```
var y = FF1.getSheetByName("sheet1").getRange('B3:B1400').getValues();

var minutes = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("anothersheet").getRange('F3').getValues();

//F3 cell is equal to 00:10:00.000 and data in B3:B1400 has the same duration format

function MoreThan_10minutes(){
 //Logger.log(y);
 //Logger.log(minutes);
  if(y >= minutes) {
    Logger.log(y);
    var setvalue2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("somesheet").getRange('C3:C1400').setValues(y);  

  }else{
    var setvalue3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("somesheet").getRange('C3').setValue("no data");  
  }
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing a sheet data that's similar to your actual spreadsheet for replication? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sure! Here are the source sheet and the sheet where Im supposed to retrieve the mentioned data.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13IDSmg6ifesarfomWw0U7kP46TTvyCfWpkfraGqF8bY/edit#gid=0

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wLn0Xmb2hzEVUXs6bUPEFFEjDwGEwosC5DJwrIxi7AI/edit#gid=1316187208

Comment: Your script seems to be incomplete. Thus, it is quite hard to reproduce your exact script setup. Perhaps you can first try formatting both `F3` and `B3:B1400` the values to `mm:ss` like this sample `Utilities.formatDate(new Date(FF1.getSheetByName("sheet1").getRange('F3').getValue()), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'mm:ss'))` and then do the comparison after. See [Working with Dates and Times](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the range when the duration time of the column "B" is over 10 minutes using Google Apps Script/

#### Modification points:

- In this case, it is required to adjust the value retrieved with `getValues`.

  - In this answer, at first, the retrieved values are converted to the RFC3339 format and the offset `new Date("1899-12-30T00:00:00Z").getTime()` is subtracted from the converted value. By this, the duration time can be obtained.

When these points are reflected to the sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const check = 10; // 10 minutes from "I'm trying to retrieve only the cells where the duration is more or equal than 10 minutes.""

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const timeZone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  const values = sheet.getRange("B1:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const offset = new Date("1899-12-30T00:00:00Z").getTime(); // For Google Spreadsheet
  const res = values.reduce((ar, [b], i) => {
    const v = (new Date(Utilities.formatDate(b, timeZone, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")).getTime() - offset) / (1000 * 60);
    if (v > check) ar.push(`B${i + 1}`); // or, you want to retrieve the value as minutes, ar.push(v);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  console.log(res)
}
```

- When this script is run using your provided Spreadsheet, the ranges of `[ 'B6', 'B12', 'B13', 'B20' ]` are returned as the A1Notation.
- When you want to retrieve the result as the value of minutes, please modify `ar.push(`B${i + 1}`)` to `ar.push(v)`.

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided sample Spreadsheet. When the Spreadsheet is changed, this script might not be able to be used. So please be careful about this. First, please test this script using your provided sample Spreadsheet.

#### References:

- [RFC3339](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339)
- [Epoch (computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing))
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: This seems like a very good solution, but would you be so kind to adapt it to get the values from a different spreadsheet? I'm using spreadsheet.openbyid. Its beacuse the values are being retrieved from another spreadsheet.

Comment: Also, how can I declare where to place the retrieved values? Like in C3 or something like that.

Comment: @mau Thank you for replying. About your 2nd new question of `would you be so kind to adapt it to get the values from a different spreadsheet?`, please modify `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` to `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###spreadsheetId###");`. About your 3rd new question of `Also, how can I declare where to place the retrieved values? Like in C3 or something like that`, please add `sheet.getRange("C3").setValue(res.join(","))` after the line of `console.log(res)`. But I cannot imagine your goal of 3rd question. If I misunderstood it, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

#Your code has some issues

```
function MoreThan_10minutes(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  const y = sh.getRange('B3:B1400').getValues();
 Logger.log(JSON.stringify(y));
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('anothersheet');
  const minutes = sh1.getRabge('F3').getValue();
 //Logger.log(minutes);

 //You cannot compare y and minutes like the next line because Y is a 2d array and minutes is either a single value
  if(y >= minutes) {
```

Comment: How can I accomplish that instead then?

Comment: How about starting by explaining what you want

Comment: Retrieving data from a different spreadsheet that has values more or equal than 10 minutes